# When I select one vertex it selects multiple vertices?

Tags: 3dsmax, vertex

I'm trying to do some kind of a face. When I select a vertex it selects two other vertices. However, when I try to select one of the two other vertices it doesn't select them.

I want to move only one vertex to make it right.

My model is an editable poly.

[Link](http://www.4shared.com/file/9y92mqSQ/face.html?) to my model so if you want to inspect it properly.

**Front view :**

[image: Front View]

**Linked vertices :**

[image: The selected vertices]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use 3DS max, so I can't give you specific direction, but I can tell you generally what's happening. I assume you were following some kind of tutorial, so you may not remember doing this. However, it looks like **you have the model set up to be mirrored down the center**. So, selecting one vertex will mirror to the other side. Typically this is very useful for creating symmetrical models like a face. However, if you want the model to be asymmetrical, it's not so useful. Here's [a video](http://designreform.net/2008/05/3ds-max-mirror-modifier) showing the use of mirror.

I suggest keeping this mirror mode on until you're finished making most of the changes to your model. Then, when you're done with that, disable it and make your asymmetrical changes.

Sorry I don't know exactly how to disable it.